# Serialization of Netty objects in Akka

Tags: scala, serialization, netty, akka

I'm using [Socko](http://sockoweb.org/) which is an Akka based web server that uses Netty for its networking. I've been trying to log Socko WebSocketFrameEvent in an [Evntsourced](https://github.com/eligosource/eventsourced) persistence storage. Every time I tried to pass a WebSocketFrameEvent to be logged I get the following error

> java.io.NotSerializableException: org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioAcceptedSocketChannel

I was told that it could that this error is cuased by Netty's NioAcceptedSocketChannel not being serialized, while Akka messages are. I found Netty's [serialization package](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/serialization/package-summary.html) but I'm unsure of how to list the Netty serialization package in the [Akka configuration file](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/serialization.html) to serialize the messages that contain Netty's NioAcceptedSocketChannel. My current application.conf file contains the following for serialization:

```
serializers {
    netty = "org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.serialization"
}
serialization-bindings {
    "org.mashupbots.socko.events.WebSocketFrameEvent" = java
}
```

When I try run my application I get the following error, even though I have resolved the Netty dependency with SBT:

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.serialization

Comment: It seems that `NioAcceptedSocketChannel` is contained inside `WebSocketFrameEvent`, and you just cannot serialize `SocketChannel` because it does not make sense - how do you serialize a socket connection? I'm afraid that you won't be able to serialize `WebSocketFrameEvent` at all. Second, `serializers` section in `application.conf` is not defined like this, not to mention that Netty serializators are hardly compatible with what Akka expects. I suggest reading [official documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.1/scala/serialization.html) on that if you are interested.

Comment: Well, you may be able to serialize `WebSocketFrameEvent`, but I think you have to write an implementation of `akka.serialization.Serializer` just for this class.

Comment: Do you happen to have a working example of implementing a custom serializer? I see there is a step by step process in the Akka documentation but I want to see what I would have to fill in were there are blank spaces.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't have any. I never used this functionality yet.

Comment: `org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.serialization` is probably not a class, and probably not a `akka.serialization.Serializer` class